# upload files to amazon s3 directly with php

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-s3

solved: using this post :  http://www.designedbyaturtle.co.uk/2013/direct-upload-to-s3-with-a-little-help-from-jquery/

edit: I'm looking for a way to directly upload a big zip file from client side to amazon s3 without first uploading it to my server

I'm using a small server for my web application with laravel framework
I have some users trying to upload big files to my servr (around 300-400m), and my server is to weak and my bandwidth is to low for the user to be able to finish uploading.

I want the file to be uploaded directly to amazon s3,
from browsing around i dont think this can be dont with laravel sdk for amazon

I installed the official sdk
and I'm trying to do it like suggested in this post
[uploading posted file to amazon s3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22224724/uploading-posted-file-to-amazon-s3/27680430#27680430)

but not rally sure how to actually send my file to amazon s3,
what should i put instad of 'string of your file here':

```
 $result = $client->upload(
'BUCKET HERE',
'OBJECT KEY HERE',
'STRING OF YOUR FILE HERE',
'public-read' // public access ACL
);
```

im getting my file like this :

```
$myFile = Input::file('file');
```

putting $myfile instead of 'string of your file here' doesnt work

Comment: Have you tried `$myFile->getRealPath()`

Comment: i actually get $myfile as an array cause it could be multiple file uploades, but anyway, $myFile[0]->getRealPath has a value of bool(false) which i dont think is what it suppose to have,and trying to send it gives an invalid resource type.  i tried manuualy putting a path to a file on my server, and it doesnt work, just put on s3 a file with the path as its content

Comment: It's weird that `getRealPath()` is not working correctly. Anyways. Try using `file_get_contents('path-to-your-file')` as string of your file

Comment: well, it works with a regular txt file, but it doesnt help my send the uploaded file without uploading it first to my server. plus my uploaded file is a zip file, so file_get_contents doesnt work

Comment: The uploaded file (`Input::file()`) has already been uploaded to your server. It stored somewhere as a temporary file. It's just a matter of getting that filepath and then getting its contents.

Comment: I see, I'm looking for a way to upload my file stright to amazon. without uploading to my server (mainly cause my server has a slow bandwidth and fails to finish the upload), any suggestion?

Comment: No not really. I also do not have any real experience with Amazon S3. I suggest you re-formulate your question a bit, I'm sure someone might know the answer

Comment: Instead of editing your question saying "solved" please answer your own question (with some code examples if possible) and accept it (you'll have to wait 48 hours to do that). This way the question is clearly marked as solved and it might help others. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I solved the problem using this post: solved: using this post : http://www.designedbyaturtle.co.uk/2013/direct-upload-to-s3-with-a-little-help-from-jquery/

Comment: Link is broken.

Answer (score 1):

You can upload files directly from the client side to S3, but it's a security risk as you can't validate the file, plus giving anyone access to your S3 buckets is just generally a bad idea. I would still look at uploading via your Laravel application.

All files uploaded to PHP are stored on your server, most likely in the `/tmp` directory for Linux and Mac machines. There's no way to avoid that, the file needs to be stored somewhere. You obtain an object representing the file using `Input::file('file')`.

The file is an instance of `Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile`, which exposes a `getRealPath()` method. We can then use `fopen()` to read the contents of the file as a string. So to upload it to S3, use:

```
$client->upload(
  'bucket',
  'key',
  fopen($file->getRealPath(), 'r'),
  'public-read',
);
```